# Calculus of variation,minimizing sequence exists.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $F(x,z,p)$ be  $C^1$ in $\Omega\times R\times R^n $ where $\Omega$ is bounded domain.
Assume that $F(x,z,p)>\Phi(|p|)-C$ for some continuous $\Phi(s)$ satisfying that $\Phi(s)/s\rightarrow \infty\ as\ s\rightarrow \infty \ C $ is constant.
Show that every minimizing sequence of $\int F(x,u(x),\nabla u(x))dx,$ $u\in W^{1,1}_0(\Omega)$
contains a subsequence $\{u_{k_j}\}$,$u_{k_j}\rightarrow u$ and $\nabla u_{k_j}\rightharpoonup \nabla u$ for some $u\in W^{1,1}_0(\Omega)$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ and $L^1(\Omega ;R)$ 
My basic idea is to invoke that a sequence uniformly bounded in $L^1(\Omega)$ and that is uniformly integrable, then it has a subsequence weak star converges in $L^1(\Omega)$, here perfectly the same with weak converge. It only remains to show the gradient sequence is uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy is good (although I'm confused by the brief appearance of weak* convergence; it is standard that a uniformly integrable sequence has a   weakly convergent subsequence). The uniform integrability of a minimizing sequence is a consequence of the following lemma, applied to $w_k=|\nabla u_k|$.

**Lemma**. Suppose that $(w_\alpha)$ is a sequence of functions such that $\int \Phi(w_\alpha)\le M$, where $M$ is a constant and $\Phi$ is as in your post. Then $(w_\alpha)$ is uniformly integrable.

*Proof*. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $K$ such that $\Phi(s)>Ms\epsilon^{-1}$ for $s\ge K$. Then for all $\alpha $ we have
$$\int_{|w_\alpha|\ge K}|w_\alpha|\le \int_{|w_\alpha|\ge K}M^{-1}\epsilon\,\Phi(|w_\alpha|)\le \epsilon$$
as required. $\Box$